# Can't Convert Char in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, char

I have a "phone" area in my database and data type is `char(11)`.

I need to make a conversion in ASP.NET C# as below:

```
char PhoneNumber = char.Parse((item.FindControl("TxtPhoneNumber") as TextBox).Text);
```

but I get an error:

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: String must be exactly one character long.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Please have a look at data type mapping between database and c# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings This should be similar for other databases (oracle, mysql, etc) In c# `char` is a type which represents one character. You cannot parse a string into one character except the string is exactly one char long (as the error message mentions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

char.Parse shall take a string of length 1 and shall return a char value. If you want to convert your textboxt content to char array you can do like below:

```
string PhoneNumberstr = (item.FindControl("TxtPhoneNumber") as TextBox).Text);
char[] PhoneNumber = PhoneNumberstr.ToCharArray();
```

Comment: The answer shows how to convert a string to char array, but how are you going to save the char array in the database `CHAR(11)` field? You will have to do another conversion back to string. So what's the point? Just send the original string directly to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert it. The database `CHAR` type is a string type. The only difference is that the `CHAR` length is fixed (in your case 11 characters).

So just send your string as is:

```
string PhoneNumber = (item.FindControl("TxtPhoneNumber") as TextBox).Text;
```

Note: The database `CHAR` type is not the same as the `char` type in c#, which is used to store one single character.

Comment: This is the actual answer to the OP's question.